# Drawing on Form_Load C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, paint, form-load

I'm drawing something on my panel with a method and when I call this method via a button it does draw, but when I call this method on `Form_Load` it doesn't draw anything. When I debug it, it actually goes through the code without any problem, but still it won't draw anything.

below you can see the `Form_Load` and the `Button_Click` events:

```
private: System::Void SelectElementForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if (ElementList->Count > 0)
    {
        Index = 0;
        DrawLinesInLayout();
    }
}
```

and the button

```
private: System::Void btnLeft_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    if (ElementList->Count > 0)
    {
        if (Index + 1 > 1)
        {
            Index--;
            DrawLinesInLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            Index = ElementList->Count - 1;
            DrawLinesInLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the `Paint-event` it works for when my form pops up. But then I got the code twice in my program which is kinda pointless.

So my questions are:

- Why isn't my Form_load using my method correctly and my button is?
- Can I call the `Paint` event on a button click?

Comment: Yes, it is quite pointless to keep your original code.  Splattering pixels to a window that isn't yet visible is a waste of time.  Delete it.  Call Invalidate() when you need the Paint event to run again.

Comment: @Hans Call Invalidate() doesnt work for me, It just redraws my first `Paint` event. I've got some variables in my `Paint` event that changes when I press the buttons.

Comment: Solved it by using the `Shown` event instead of the `Load` event

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant mentioned, you can't draw on something that isn't there yet.
Solution: draw after it is created.

`Invalidate();` doesn't work since there are variables that change in the drawing method (that's why there is an `Index`change in each call event).

Instead of using the `Load` event, use the `Shown` event. This will draw the lines on the form:

```
private: System::Void SelectElementForm_Shown(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    if (ElementList->Count > 0)
    {
        Index = 0;
        DrawLinesInLayout();
    }
}
```